# "Unrecognized configuration section connectionStrings."

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration, connection-string

I had been working on a project in VS2005 that utilized a local connection to an Access DB.

In the past week, I installed .NET framework 3.5 for use w/ a different project as well as VS6.

I went back to my VS2005 application and suddenly there are big issues:

In the designer for any class utilizing my OLEDB connection showed this:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to
>   type 'System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection'.  Hide
>
> at System.Configuration.Configuration.get_ConnectionStrings() at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.ConfigurationHelperService.ReadConnectionStrings(String
>   configFileName, DocData configDocData, String prefix) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.AppConfigSerializer.Deserialize(DesignTimeSettings
>   Settings, String SectionName, DocData AppConfigDocData, MergeValueMode
>   mergeMode, IUIService UIService) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsGlobalObjects.SettingsFileGlobalObject.LoadSettings(String
>   fileName) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsGlobalObjects.SettingsFileGlobalObject.BuildType()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsGlobalObjects.SettingsFileGlobalObject.GetObjectType()
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalType.get_ObjectType() at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObject.GetHashCode() at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectService.GlobalKey.GetHashCode()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T
>   obj) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectService.GetGlobalObjects(Type
>   baseType) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.GlobalObjectService.GetGlobalObjects()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetTypeFromGlobalObjects(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.AggregateTypeResolutionService.GetType(String
>   name, Boolean throwOnError) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.GetType(ITypeResolutionService
>   trs, String name, Dictionary`2 names) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.FillStatementTable(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, IDictionary table, Dictionary`2 names,
>   CodeStatementCollection statements, String className) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   serializationManager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
>   fReload)

And when I ran the app, I encounter the following exception on startup:

> "Unrecognized configuration section connectionStrings."

In looking online, these issues seem to commonly relate to things built in VS2005 and deployed on .net 1.1 framework; but this is all running as a windows forms application locally within VS (not on IIS).  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS2K5 to no avail.

Any thoughts?
Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 8):

This is a really old post, i know, but i have had the same problem recently, i have fixed it by putting:

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="appSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
    <section name="connectionStrings" type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" requirePermission="false"/>
 <configSections>
```

before my connection strings:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="XXX" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=user;Password=pw;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

so my app.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
     <configSections>
        <section name="appSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="connectionStrings" type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" requirePermission="false"/>
     <configSections>   
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="XXX" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=user;Password=pw;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

In C# I am using below code to retrieve my connection string:

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("myApp.config"); //Path to your config file
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
this.connectionString = configuration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: This worked for me, though the appSettings section isn't necessary (unless you're using it in the config)

Answer (score 6):

This is a wild guess... but I think I've seen this before when you have something before the <configSections> element in your web.config. For example, this would cause an error:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings [...] />
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name=[...] />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

The <configSections> element needs to come first:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name=[...] />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings [...] />
</configuration>
```

Probably not what's causing your problem but I thought I'd mention it...

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I don't believe this is the case, my app.config is as follows:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Mockups.Properties.Settings.MockupDSConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MockupDS.mdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: I think there's something misconfigured - unfortunately, uninstalling/installing things doesn't seem to fix it.

Even when I try to create a new DataSource connection - in the connection wizard - I choose the OLE DB connection, choose the .mdb and click "Ok" and I get a pop-up saying "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." and that's it!

Very frustrating....

Comment: I was banging my head for a bit trying to figure out why my App.config wasn't working for some custom types - and this was the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i had been facing the same issue.please check your machine.config file.

```
<configuration>
 <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"/>
 <configSections>
  <section name="appSettings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
  <section name="connectionStrings" type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" requirePermission="false"/>
```

and when i removed the

> ..system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"/>

it again worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

It was the camelCase issue in my case. Both `<connectionStrings>` and `<connectionstrings>` work but it should be the same in the section name and within connection string itself.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="default"
         connectionString=[...] />
  </connectionStrings>
```